Can I do touch-ups of finish losses on my vintage furniture?
I have this old mid-century credenza that has some kind of finish on it (it's sold wood not cheap stuff). It's in great shape and only has a few very small scratches and a penny sized spot where the finish is chipped off - not very noticeable.
I'm not sanding and refinishing this thing because I don't need to. But can I paint in a little polycoat to fill in these scratches and spots?
It looks great as is so I'm just being persnickety, but if I can do anything to hide them better it would be nice. Doesn't need to be perfect just something to somewhat match the finished shine/color.
Edit
I realized its silly not to include a pic. I don't want to do the whole thing for anonymity's sake, but here is a pic of the penny-sized chip. You can see the finished colour and that of the wood under it.
Also, kind of curious what sort of wood it is if anyone knows because that might be helpful for figuring out how to touch it up. Tried to take a good pic, I think it's darker than the pic shows and shinier.
Also, I found there are spots under parts of the piece that aren't visible that are not finished at all which is awesome because I could test out different stuff there first to find a good match!


By polycoat, are you speaking of a clear finish or something that contains/alters color?

Surely, you can but it might have the opposite effect to what you're looking to do. It might make the minor blemishes stand out even more. Can you share more about the "polycoat" you're planning on using?

Im not sure what the coat is, its from the mid 60s. When I look at the chip it appears to be a slightly lighter color, but maybe its just a clear coat and it makes it look darker? Its a plasticky sort of shiny thing.

"I have this old mid century credenza that has some kind of polycoat on it" The primary commercial finish used throughout the 2nd half of the 20th century was lacquer, specifically nitrocellulose lacquer. Odds are that's what's on your piece. "(its sold wood not cheap stuff)." Just as a general FYI, lots (and lots and lots) of MCM furniture features plywood with good hardwood veneers on it. Use of plywood or another manmade board is by no means a sign of cheaper construction or lesser value in the right context.

I just meant to imply hard wood (which I've always assumed was more expensive)? Maybe its plywood but its insanely heavy which makes me think its a different kind.

Thanks for the added photo, it makes the Q much more valuable to future readers.

"Also, kind of curious what sort of wood it is if anyone knows" The decision was taken early on that wood IDs would be off topic here, which was wise as wood identification is notoriously difficult to do from photos, sometimes outright impossible. (It can actually be incredibly hard even with the wood in front of you!) We generally try to help informally, but one of the key issues with IDs is the number of lookalike species, which may or may not be related. Your wood is unfortunately one of those as it's "mahoganylike". It may be one of the real mahoganies, or a lookalike unrelated species.

I edited the body text to remove the word veneer, which has a specific meaning different to how you're using it here.

Thanks for all the help! I didn't realize wood identification was so difficult. Can I assume it was "nitrocellulose lacquer"? Is there a product I can try on it? Like I said there are hidden parts I can test it on without affecting the piece.


But can I paint in a little polycoat to fill in these scratches and spots?

Well there are no finish police (much as some people would like to have the badge!) so you can of course. But it may not give the result you're hoping for visually.
The key issues are likely to be:

resultant colour of the retouched areas (always a potential problem with touchups, especially spot-retouching);
surface finish — an exact match of gloss level is nearly never achievable with finishes straight from the container (meaning you have to mix-to-match, or modify the finish after application);
the edges of each area of finish loss remaining visible to catch the light and telegraph their location.

The last is why it's nearly always necessary to do at least some sanding or other abrasion, to feather out the edges of the remaining finish and allow the new finish to more easily transition seamlessly into it.
Now, since "polycoat" isn't a known term I'll assume you mean a polyurethane finish of some kind. But there are two main types consumers use and they are entirely different in almost all ways. And most importantly here, that includes colour — waterbased polyurethanes are naturally colourless, while oil-based polyurethane varnishes have some sort of yellow-orange or amber colouration.
There's no perfect solution with this sort of thing. It is possible oil-based will work here, but you'll have to try it out in one of the less-visible spots to see.
You'd likely get a better result using a spraycan lacquer, or shellac. In part because they lay on coats very thinly and evenly which is so much more difficult by brush. There are other advantages too, including the much faster drying time of both finishes. Also with lacquer specifically the solvents in it will allow it to meld with the existing lacquer to some extent, rather than merely clinging to the surface as a dissimilar finish will.

I just added a pic, my phone sucks so it doesn't capture the color that well, but maybe you can at least see the texture and discern what I might want to use?

Those losses, and the colour of the wood itself (not dirty, or otherwise affected by the finish loss), suggest you're in line for a good result with spot-retouching. In terms of what to use, all the above still holds.

Do you recommend a specific product (not brand but type of product)? I'm thinking something I can just paint on with a little brush.

No, my Answer covers what I see as the viable options — "It is possible oil-based [polyurethane] will work here" and "You'd likely get a better result using a spraycan lacquer, or shellac". There's no way of knowing in advance what'll work best unfortunately. If you don't want to get a can of lacquer or shellac (and if you're not doing more than this one project a single can is more than you need) then oil-based polyurethane varnish is worth trying, and sometimes quite small cans of this are available so it would be inexpensive to test it out. You'll also need some mineral spirits. [contd]

I would recommend thinning the varnish down to create what's called wiping varnish, see here, and then applying it either by brush or by wiping/dabbing on, after which you'll wipe away some or all excess. This will require building the finish up in layers with drying time in between, but it's very controllable, almost zero chance of dust landing into the drying finish and automatically allows you to feather into the surrounding area in a way that brush alone does not.

Are you not allowed to recommend a specific product? Literally all oil-based polyurethane varnishes I see on amazon are huge cans. The smaller bottles seem to be water-based exclusively.

No it's totally fine for members to offer suggestions or outright recommend stuff (although asking in a Question is off topic as there's a global rule against shopping Qs). But I'm not in your market. I would caution not to automatically buy Minwax, it's often the cheapest for good reason; as a rule one can do better, sometimes a lot better. The main thing is I think you should make the decision for yourself based on multiple reviews, weigh a range of opinions rather than go by just one rando's recommendation... same as anything really. Plus I feel local availability should be factored in.
